# Remove variable from base URL with htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, url, variables

I've been trying to rewrite a URL such as

> www.somesite.com/?x=372

into a url

> www.somesite.com/

My current code does not seem to work

> RewriteEngine On
>
> RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} x=(.*)
>
> RewriteRule http://www.somesite.com/ [R=301,L]

I've looked up countless ways of trying to do it with htaccess and still no success.

Comment: See how `QSD` flag works : https://amitoverflow.com/2021/03/17/mod-rewrite-qsd-flag-and-its-uses-in-htaccess/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you simply want to redirect a client to remove the query string (everything after the **`?`** in the URL), then you can try this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} x=(.*)
RewriteRule ^ http://www.somesite.com/? [R=301,L]
```

You've got most of it right, it seems, but your rule needs to have a match, and your target (the `http://www.somesite.com/`) needs a **`?`** at the end so that any query string before the rewrite won't get appended.

In Apache 2.4 or newer you can use the QSD [query string discard flag](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/flags.html#flag_qsd):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} x=(.*)
RewriteRule .* http://www.somesite.com/ [R=301,L,QSD]
```