# rewrite url using htacess

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have test project folder called "prj". In that, I have one file called test.php.I want something like

```
http://localhost/prj/test.php?t=123
```

should be rewritten like

```
http://localhost/prj/test.php
```

any help will be appreciated

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11803411/remove-variable-from-base-url-with-htaccess

Comment: @TimJoyce : not its not dulpication. I just want to rewrite url. not redirect to it by deleting querystring.

Comment: Can you explain more your needs ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a .htaccess file with:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^prj\/test.php$ prj/test.php?t=123 [NC]
```

**Edit**

If your htaccess file is located in the prj folder:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^test.php$ test.php?t=123 [NC]
```

Comment: 1) Where is your htaccess file located? Because if it's in the prj map you should remove "prj" and it will become: RewriteRule ^test.php$ test.php?t=123 [NC]

2) Make sure AllowOverride in httpd.config is set to All.

Comment: still not able to achieve goal. any other suggestions?