# how to remove = and ? from URL in php

Tags: php, mysql, .htaccess

I want to remove ? and = from my URL "http://localhost/G-Zip/offices-view.php?id=11041" using .htaccess.
I used this code to remove extension from URL.

## Remove .PHP From URL

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

Comment: Removing `?` and `=` form the url would leave you with `http://localhost/G-Zip/offices-view.phpid11041` which probably won't be parsed by PHP. What's the use?

Comment: its possible if you use `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` like "MVC 5", then `explode()` the URL and TRIM

Comment: Try this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11803411/remove-variable-from-base-url-with-htaccess

Comment: Possible duplicate of [htaccess remove the parameter from url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37722694/htaccess-remove-the-parameter-from-url)

Comment: it is still not working :(

Comment: @kerbholz i just want to remove ? and id=11041 from the url by using .htaccess

Comment: In `.htaccess`? Your title suggests you want to do it in PHP! What is it?

Comment: yes if it possible but after i searched in many websites i realized that the way to do that without any affects on links is .htaccess .

Comment: Take a look at the [QSD|qsdiscard](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/trunk/en/rewrite/flags.html#flag_qsd) rewrite flag

Answer (score 0):

Try str_replace() Function in PHP:

```
echo str_replace("?",""," http://localhost/G-Zip/offices-view.php?id=11041");
```

The above code would remove ? from the URL

```
echo str_replace("=",""," http://localhost/G-Zip/offices-view.php?id=11041");
```

The above code would remove = from URL